# Finding the cause of: "The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry."

Tags: jsf, primefaces

Is there any way to determine what line (or even what file) is causing the

> The form component needs to have a UIForm in its ancestry. Suggestion: enclose the necessary components within

warning message from Primefaces? I just began working on an established project with many, many .xhtml files (written by others) with all sorts of templates and inheritance and I'm having trouble narrowing down what file is causing the issue.

I've tried googling with no luck, and I can't find an answer on SO that addresses how to *find* the source of the error.

**Update**: It's not as simple as going to the page shown in the url. For example, the warning displays when I navigate to `'../foo.xhtml'`, however, `foo.xhtml` implements a template and inclues multiple other `.xhtml` files (which in turn each include a few more `.xhtml` files). All of the files are somewhat sizeable (at least 500 lines).

Comment: What page should be clear, right? Since you get this in a page (or is this server logging?) Tried increasing the log level?

Comment: @Kukeltje No, actually. I'll update the question.

Comment: Also, it isn't logged out anywhere, it's just a primefaces growl message that displays when the page is loaded.

Comment: So you **know** what page it is. Then start reducing your page. It is as simple as that. Remove the templates etc.. That is how to find the cause. Should not take more than 5 minutes.

Comment: @Kukeltje - not when there are multiple templates and include statements. And it's about impossible to start commenting pages out, because then references to other included files cause exceptions.

Comment: Ok, if you say so... my experience is otherwise... also with some more complex pages...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Put a debug breakpoint in [`FormOmittedChecker#check()`](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/application/view/FormOmittedChecker.java#FormOmittedChecker), inside the `if` block where `isInNeedOfForm(component)` has returned `true`, which is [line 99](http://grepcode.com/file/repo1.maven.org/maven2/org.glassfish/javax.faces/2.2.12/com/sun/faces/application/view/FormOmittedChecker.java#99) as of Mojarra 2.2.12.

```
   96                    if (isForm(component)) {
   97                        result = VisitResult.REJECT;
   98                    } else if (isInNeedOfForm(component)) {
*  99                        addFormOmittedMessage(finalContext);
  100                    }
```

Given a page with an input field without a `<h:form>`,

```
<h:inputText id="someInputText" />
```

the breakpoint hit will look like below in Eclipse:

[image]

As you see on the screenshot, you can inspect `component` variable in the variables stack and then inspect its `clientId` (or `id`) property. Finally you can just locate and correlate it in generated HTML output and/or JSF source code.

I however do agree that the message should contain better diagnostic. This was fixed in Mojarra 2.3.0-m04 as per [issue 4026](https://java.net/jira/browse/JAVASERVERFACES-4026).

Comment: Thanks for the response! I will try this ASAP.

Comment: Worked like a charm! I wish I could do more than upvote and accept. Thank you so much!

Comment: You're welcome. You could consider starting a bounty and let it run for the full week.